# 10709: connect failed (no reachable host left) hdbsql

Tags: hana

I have logged in to the SAP HANA server and trying to create databases but when I start the SAP HANA Database interactive terminal I cannot execute any of the query and I am getting the below error for everything.

> 10709: connect failed (no reachable host left)

Since I am new to SAP HANA please could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the "nobody is home" answer to your connection request.
If you're sure that the HANA server is up and running (maybe double check via terminal and HDB info) then the next most likely reason for your error message is that you are using the wrong connection parameters.
Check the hostname and the port you want to connect to.

Comment: Yes I checked again the HANA server is running and I can also go up to  **hdbsql=>**.But in that if I type **\s** or any other I am getting the above error.

Comment: hdbsql doesn't immediately try a connection. Only after the first [ENTER] the database connection is tried.

Comment: In case you called hdbsql without any paramters, then that's your mistake right there. Call it with the connection parameters.

Comment: Br.Thanks a lot.Now when I call hdbsql with parameters it shows the following error.  **hdbsql: command not found**.I tried the command **hdbsql  -n localhost -i 00 -u SYSTEM -p pass** .Could you please help me?Thanks.

Comment: Ok, you might want to connect to the external IP/hostname instead of localhost. If I'm not mistaken, the default setup doesn't bind against localhost.